# Why is my alternate CSS not affecting ALL my page titles?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, custom-masterpage, style.css

I have a custom css style sheet changing the format of my page titles. This is what I have so far:

```
#s4-titlerow {
    background-color:gray;
}

#DeltaTopNavigation{
    display:none;
}
#pageTitle{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

This turns a site wide bar at the top of the page grey and the site title inside it white. It works perfectly on the homepage, however. On the other pages the grey bar appears but the title retains its default formatting. clearly `#pageTitle` is the wrong ID but I can't find the right one (and yes I have tried the F12 element inspector).

Comment: **On the other pages**: which other pages exactly? Site Pages you created or any other layouts(like settings and site contents) pages?

Comment: That's interesting. The CSS is affecting the pageTitle of system pages but not site pages but it is affecting the s4 area of both types.

Comment: Try adding same CSS to anchor tags within page title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the same CSS to anchor tag within heading with title `#pageTitle`.

Try using:

```
#pageTitle, #pageTitle a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or

```
#pageTitle {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#pageTitle a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or

```
.ms-core-pageTitle, ms-core-pageTitle a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Maybe you can add `!important` to some of the CSS properties.

Comment: close enough, I had to make a copy of the #pageTitle entry and add the a tag to it. apparently #pageTitle affects system pages and #pageTitle a affects site pages... who knew?